# Get commission of all user according to their transaction issued

Tags: php, mysql

```
I have two tables   Transaction Table :-         
1       txn_id                      
2       txn_issued_by  (mid)        
3       dist_id                 
4       amount                  
5       bank_name           
6       account_no          
7       ben_name            
8       ben_contact         
9       date_of_transaction         
10      date_of_txn_modify          
11      txn_status          
12      bank_response_code          
13      status      
14      modify_by           
15      comm_amount_agent           
16      comm_amount_distributor     
17      comm_amount_sadmin          
18      client_name         
19      client_number           
20      client_add          
21      txn_serial_no           
22      comment_by_moderator    

2)Member Table
   - mid name username photo
```

**I just wanted to know how to process transaction to get desired result like ...**

- Get number of transaction of lies between amount 525 t0 2500
- Get number of transaction of lies between amount 2501 t0 5050
- Get number of transaction of lies between amount 5051 t0 10100
- Of all User(User Wise)
  My Code is :

```php
<?php
$q_c = "SELECT *,
      COUNT(txn_id) AS count_txn
    FROM TRANSACTION
    WHERE amount >= 525
      AND amount <= 2500
      AND txn_issued_by IN (
        SELECT mid
        FROM members
        )
    GROUP BY txn_issued_by";

$r_c = mysql_query($q_c) or die(mysql_error());
$row_c     = mysql_fetch_array($r_c);
$count_txn = $row_c['count_txn'];
?>
```

The goal is the following:

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain better what you want? This is a bit confusing. How do you identify a member in the transaction table? And you want the totals for those 3 groups or you want one query for each of the groups but have results for all users?

Comment: member is identified by txn_issued_by in transaction table.I want user wise commission for three groups of transaction.

Comment: Commission for 525 to 2500 rs. is 10 /Rs.                     Commission for 2501 to 5051 rs. is 20 /Rs.|| Commission for 5051 to 10100 rs. is 40 /Rs.

Comment: And the attached image is missing. did you intended to show it?

Comment: yes,but it does not attached with

Comment: Actually i want all commission of all user

Comment: COUNT is an aggregate function. Do you really want * with it? It doesn't make much sense. Do you want only the count for those 3 groups?

Comment: I know this,here * doesn not make any sense

Comment: yes i want to fetch all records of commission of all user in system at once as directed in images

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand, you need calculate a number of transactions and sums of amount within given ranges of amount for all users, using only one query.
In such a case a query like below might help:

```
SELECT txn_issued_by,
  SUM( CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN 525 AND 2500 
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) count_525_to_2500,
  SUM( CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN 2501 AND 5050 
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) count_2501_to_5050,
  SUM( IF( amount BETWEEN 5051 AND 10100, 1, 0 )) count_5051_to_10100,
  COUNT(*) count_total,
  SUM( CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN 525 AND 2500 
       THEN amount ELSE 0 END ) amount_525_to_2500,
  SUM( CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN 2501 AND 5050 
       THEN amount  ELSE 0 END ) amount_2501_to_5050,
  SUM( CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN 5051 AND 10100 
       THEN amount  ELSE 0 END ) amount_5051_to_10100,
  SUM( amount ) amount_total
FROM Transaction
GROUP BY txn_issued_by;
```

The query uses `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END` expression, `IF` function can also be used (pay attention to thirs SUM in the query), but I personally prefer `CASE WHEN` because `IF` is specific to MySql, while `CASE WHEN` is ANSII SQL compliant and runs on most databases. 
The below query calculates total values for all records:

```
SELECT 
  SUM( CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN 525 AND 2500 
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) count_525_to_2500,
  SUM( CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN 2501 AND 5050 
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) count_2501_to_5050,
  SUM( IF( amount BETWEEN 5051 AND 10100, 1, 0 )) count_5051_to_10100,
  COUNT(*) count_total,
  SUM( CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN 525 AND 2500 
       THEN amount ELSE 0 END ) amount_525_to_2500,
  SUM( CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN 2501 AND 5050 
       THEN amount  ELSE 0 END ) amount_2501_to_5050,
  SUM( CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN 5051 AND 10100 
       THEN amount  ELSE 0 END ) amount_5051_to_10100,
  SUM( amount ) amount_total
FROM Transaction;
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c017b/11

Comment: ok,let me try this code after that i will update you..Lots of thanks to you